# Localhost Refused to connect in chrome

Tags: node.js, express, server, backend

I am a beginner who is learning backend stuff. I am using NOdejs with Express trying to make my first own server. And whenever i type localhost/300 it shows this

**This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.**

Answer (score 1):

If you have correctly started the server then it should listen. And you are accessing it incorrectly localhost/300
I should be accessible like this **http://localhost:3000**
3000 is the port not a parameter.

Comment: Can you please upload the screen shot of code and an error ?

Comment: I found the solution I closed the terminal that is why it was showing the error. Thanks for reaching out

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i closed the terminal and that is why it showed this error. it works now